# Flutter Unexpected Null Value when calling a localized string

Tags: flutter

I'm getting the following Error when running my multilingual app

```
Restarted application in 87ms.
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following TypeErrorImpl was thrown building Main(dirty):
Unexpected null value.
The relevant error-causing widget was:
Main
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 288:49      throw_
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 606:63  nullCheck
packages/flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart 69:73                        of
packages/fids/main.dart 44:67                                                     build
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5156:22                               build
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5086:15                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4805:7                                rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5068:5                                [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5062:5                                mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3971:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3708:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5111:16                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4805:7                                rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5068:5                                [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5062:5                                mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3971:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3708:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5111:16                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5251:11                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4805:7                                rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5068:5                                [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5242:11                               [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5062:5                                mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3971:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3708:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5111:16                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4805:7                                rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5068:5                                [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5062:5                                mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3971:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3708:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5111:16                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4805:7                                rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5068:5                                [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5062:5                                mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3971:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3708:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart 1240:16                                 [_rebuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart 1209:5                                  mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart 1156:16                                 <fn>
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 2720:19                               buildScope
packages/flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart 1155:12                                 attachToRenderTree
packages/flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart 987:24                                  attachRootWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart 968:7                                   <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/isolate_helper.dart 48:19           internalCallback
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

the app contains many subfiles but I've narrowed down the problem to a specific string I'm getting from a `AppLocalizations.of(context)` in my `main.dart` file that is just a material app calling my `app_bar.dart` file. of put both files below and highlighted the string that is throwing the error.

**`main.dart`**

```
import './src/src.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const Main());
}

class Main extends StatelessWidget {
  const Main({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
          fontFamily: AppVars.appLocale == "fa"
              ? "IRANSans"
              : AppVars.appLocale == "ar"
                  ? "Baloo"
                  : "open-sans",
          useMaterial3: true,
          colorScheme: const ColorScheme(
              brightness: Brightness.light,
              primary: AppColors.primary,
              onPrimary: AppColors.onPrimary,
              secondary: AppColors.secondary,
              onSecondary: AppColors.onSecondary,
              error: AppColors.error,
              onError: AppColors.onError,
              background: AppColors.background,
              onBackground: AppColors.onBackground,
              surface: AppColors.surface,
              onSurface: AppColors.onSurface)),
      supportedLocales: const [
        Locale('en'),
        Locale('fa'),
        Locale('ar'),
      ],
      locale: Locale("en"),
      localizationsDelegates: const [
        AppLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      home: CustomAppBar(appBarText: AppLocalizations.of(context).pageTitle),

      // >>>>>>>      THE ABOVE LINE IS THE PROBLEM.     <<<<<<<<
    );
  }
}
```

**`app_bar.dart`**

```
import '../src.dart';

class CustomAppBar extends StatelessWidget {
  final String appBarText;
  final Color appBarTextColor;
  final Color appBarColor;
  final Color appBarShadowColor;
  // final Widget body;

  const CustomAppBar({
    super.key,
    required this.appBarText,
    // required this.body,
    this.appBarColor = AppColors.primary,
    this.appBarTextColor = AppColors.onPrimary,
    this.appBarShadowColor = AppColors.onBackground,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        toolbarHeight: 80,
        title: Text(
          appBarText,
          style: TextStyle(color: appBarTextColor, fontSize: 40),
        ),
        backgroundColor: appBarColor,
        shadowColor: appBarShadowColor,
        elevation: 10,
        leadingWidth: 150,
        leading: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 5, 0, 5),
          child: Image(
            image: AssetImage(AppImages.iacImage),
            fit: BoxFit.contain,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(),
    );
  }
}
```

if appBarText to a normal "string" the app works fine.

I also used an extension like below

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart';

extension BuilContextExtensions on BuildContext {
  AppLocalizations get strings => AppLocalizations.of(this);
}
```

so I can use `context.strings.pageTitle` instead of `AppLocalizations.of(context).pageTitle` but I removed it hoping that would fix the problem though it didn't.

I have already tried `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get`. they did not fix the problem.